# Ensure session store complete before login redirect

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js, node.js-connect

In an express node app using the passport library for authentication, I'm converting session storage from MemoryStore to connect-couchdb. The login page is now flaky, and I think it is because the new session storage is slow enough that it has highlighted a race.

I'm using the 'successReturnToOrRedirect:/' option in passport, and the 'session get' for / occurs before the 'session set' has written to the database. I've used some extra logging through the connect-couchdb and passport code to confirm this.

Is there a way to make sure req.session.save is called and completes before res.redirect gets called as part of success in passport? The optional callback you can pass into authenticate() replaces all builtin handling, I was hoping for a solution where it can be augmented.

Also posted [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/477)

Answer (score 0):

Sir, the one responsible for the session management is the Express and it have the necessary interface to plugin your session store like MemoryStore. And if you call the `req.session.save` you deserve a callback too :-)

```
req.session.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // Houston we have a problem
    return err;
  }

  // Session saved
})
```

Comment: The problem here is that passport.js dealing with the low level detail of checking authentication, and there is no way to manually call req.session.save before it redirects (on success). You can configure with a callback, but this replaces the entire handler.

Comment: For example, have a look at strategy.success at https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to force a session save before ALL redirects, which happens to work in my case. The only res.redirect we have is part of passport. Something like:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
   const _redirect = res.redirect;
   res.redirect = function(args) {
       if (req.session) {
           req.session.save(err => {
               if (err) {
                   // handle error
               }
              _redirect.call(res, args);
           })
       } else {
           _redirect.call(res, args);
       }
    }
}
```